# I have created a custom module for backed to add menu and submenu but it shows me on phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, template, phtml

I have created a custom module for back end Menu and sub menu but it shows me an error for phtml file.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 
'Admin_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 
'content_schedule_block1'
```

My routes.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
<route id="createmenubackend" frontName="createmenubackend">
<module name="Admin_CreateMenuBackend" before="Magento_Backend"/>
</route>
</router>
</config>
```

My createmenubackend_create_index.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

[image]

my phtml file code app/code/Admin/CreateMenuBackend/view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.pthml

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

my menu.xml file app/code/Admin/CreateMenuBackend/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
 <menu>
    <add id="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu"
       title="Commision Rule" module="Admin_CreateMenuBackend"
       sortOrder="10"
       resource="Magento_Backend::content"
       />
    <add id="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu_item"
       title="Commision Rule Generator" module="Admin_CreateMenuBackend"
       sortOrder="10" parent="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu"
       action="createmenubackend/create/index"
       resource="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu_item"
       />
  </menu>
</config>
```

My controller file path app/code/Admin/CreateMenuBackend/Controller/Adminhtml/Create/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Admin\CreateMenuBackend\Controller\Adminhtml\Create;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
protected $resultPageFactory = false;      
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
} 
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Commision Rule Generator'));
    return $resultPage;
}
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Admin_CreateMenuBackend::menu');
}
}
```

Comment: Where you want to added menu?

Comment: I have successfully added menu and sub menu but on clicking seb menu  it gave me that phtml error.@DhirenVasoya

Comment: where you create that phtml file?

Comment: its path is app/code/Admin/CreateMenuBackend/view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.pthml @DhirenVasoya

Comment: I have followed https://bsscommerce.com/blog/create-admin-menu-in-magento-2/ this tutorial to create menu.

Comment: @Prits can you please you controller code with the path?

Comment: Can share the code what you have put into the phtml file?

Comment: I have updated my phtml file , menu.xml and controller file too.@DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

Change your `routes.xml` file code as this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
     <router id="admin">
          <route id="createmenubackend" frontName="createmenubackend">
             <module name="Admin_CreateMenuBackend"/>
          </route>
     </router>
</config>
```

and try `createmenubackend_create_index.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="custommenublock" template="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Changed routes.xml with your code but still the same issue @Dhiren

Comment: Have you run all the commands again like deploy and upgrade?

Comment: Yes i have run setup:upgrade and then di:compile after that content:deploy after that clear cache but it doesn't work @Dhiren

Comment: Can share the code what you have put into the phtml file?

Comment: Updated my phtml file path and code its just a hello world that i have put in it @Dhiren

Comment: I update answer please check this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111783/discussion-between-prits-and-dhiren-vasoya).